# Parquet vs Cassandra using Spark and DataFrames

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I have come to this dilemma that I cannot choose what solution is going to be better for me. I have a very large table (couple of 100GBs) and couple of smaller (couple of GBs). In order to create my data pipeline in Spark and use spark ML I need to join these tables and do couple of GroupBy (aggregate) operations. Those operations were really slow for me so I chose to do one of these two:

- Use Cassandra and use indexing to speed the GoupBy operations.
- Use Parquet and Partitioning based on the layout of the data.

I can say that Parquet partitioning works faster and more scalable with less memory overhead that Cassandra uses. So the question is this:

If developer infers and understands the data layout and the way it is going to be used, wouldn't it better for just use Parquet since you will have more control over it? Why should I pay the price for the overhead that Cassandra causes?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Cassandra is also a good solution for analytics use cases, but in another way. Before you model your keyspaces, you have to know how you need to read the data. You can also use where and range queries, but in a hard restricted way. Sometimes you will hate this restriction, but there are reasons for these restrictions. Cassandra is not like Mysql. In MySQL the performance is not a key feature. It's more about flexibility and consistency. Cassandra is a high performance write/read database. Better in write than in read. Cassandra has also a linear scalability.

Okay, a bit about your use case: Parquet is the better option for you. This is why:

- You aggregate raw data on really large and not splitted datasets
- Your Spark ML Job sounds like a scheduled, not long-running job. (onces a week, day?)

This fits more in the use cases of Parquet. Parquet is a solution for ad-hoc analysis, filter analysis stuff. Parquet is really nice if you need to run a query 1 or 2 times a month. Parquet is also a nice solution if a marketing guy wants to know one thing and the response time is not so important. Simply and short:

- Use Cassandra if you know the queries.
- Use Cassandra if a query will be used in a daily business
- Use Cassandra if Realtime matters (I talk about a maximum of 30 seconds latency, from, customer makes an action and I can see the result in my dashboard)
- Use Parquet if Realtime doesn't matter
- Use Parquet if the query will not perform 100x a day.
- Use Parquet if you want to do batch processing stuff

Comment: Thank you for your complete answer.

Comment: I have the same situation and not sure why deploying a NoSQL data base instead of simply storing the data as Parquet. We are dealing with time series data, the users might end up with 100s TB of data. I was wondering to ingest the data into azure data lake store, and process it with azure databricks, and pass the data to Power BI. It is suggested by some of my colleagues to use time series nosql database since we might have a massive data from 2010 to 2018 and the query of data might takes a long time. Data coming from flat files and other sources in real time and batch mode

Comment: @AminMohebi Sorry for my late reply. Haven't seen it so far. If you have the money for Azure: Go for it. It will save a lot of pain. If you need to save money or there are other good reasons for not using Azure: Depends on the queries you want to perform. Cassandra can also handle 100s of TB, with a good primary key (partition key + column keys) and the right queries for it. BUT you are highly restricted in the way of accessing the data. You can also duplicate your data-sets in Cassandra. That's sometimes a recommended way to go.

Comment: But general speaking: If you don't know before how you want to access your data and the latency is not that important: Go with Parquet or Apache ORC. (or something else on HDFS). Or if you can pay it: Some serverless solution. Azure, Google Cloud, AWS etc.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on your usecase. Cassandra makes it much easier (also outside of Spark) to access your data with (limited) pseudo-SQL. That makes it a perfect fit for building online-applications on top (e.g. to display the data in an UI) of it.

Also Cassandra makes it easier if you have to deal with updates, that is not only the new data going to be ingested in your data pipeline(e.g. logs) but you also have to take care about updates (e.g. system has to handle corrections of data)

When your usecase is to do analytics with Spark (and you don't care about the topics mentioned above), it should be feasible and considerable cheaper to use Parquet/HDFS - as you've stated. With HDFS you also achieve data locality with Spark and you might have the advantage that your analytic Spark applications are even faster if you are reading large blocks of data.

Comment: "since Cassandra is optimized for random access and not for reading large blocks." That's not completely correct. Cassandra is optimized for writes. Optimized for writing in your specific order. On read level Cassandra is optimized for 
sequential reads. (Within a partition key) Outside of the partition key it's a key value storage.

Comment: Hi Philipp, you're right, my remark concerning random access was not correct. I've deleted the section. Still if just want to read the data in big junks, you might have advantagess using HDFS/Parquet since your architecture/layering is simplified.